# Hive SQL query to fill missing date values in table with nearest values

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql, date-range

I have spent days trying to figure out how to add missing dates with the nearest values in Hive with no luck. I need to use Hive SQL for this based on environment constraints. The raw table currently looks like the below table.

```
account name,available balance,Date of balance 

Peter,50000,2021-05-24
Peter,50035,2021-05-25
Peter,50035,2021-05-26
Peter,50610,2021-05-28
Peter,51710,2021-06-01
Peter,53028.1,2021-06-02
Peter,53916.1,2021-06-03
Mary,50000,2021-05-24
Mary,50035,2021-05-25
Mary,53028.1,2021-05-30
```

[Raw balance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYTZV.png)

What I need is to convert the table above to the table in below link:

```
account name,available balance,Date of balance 

Peter,50000,2021-05-24
Peter,50035,2021-05-25
Peter,50035,2021-05-26
Peter,50035,2021-05-27
Peter,50610,2021-05-28
Peter,50610,2021-05-29
Peter,50610,2021-05-30
Mary,50000,2021-05-24
Mary,50035,2021-05-25
Mary,50035,2021-05-26
Mary,50035,2021-05-27
Mary,50035,2021-05-28
Mary,50035,2021-05-29
Mary,53028.1,2021-05-30
```

[Converted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSZgr.png)

Can anyone please share the Hive SQL logic to make this change please?

Comment: Could you please post  data as plain text with dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format to reduce work necessary to reproduce your example.

Comment: – leftjoin I've updated the post with comma delimited plain data. Does this help making the task easier?

Comment: Sure, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get next date using lead() function, calculate difference in days, get string of spaces with length = diff in days, split, use posexplode to generate rows, use position to add to date to get missing dates:

```
with mytable as (--Demo dataset, use your table instead of this
select stack(10, --number of tuples
'Peter',float(50000),'2021-05-24',
'Peter',float(50035),'2021-05-25',
'Peter',float(50035),'2021-05-26',
'Peter',float(50610),'2021-05-28',
'Peter',float(51710),'2021-06-01',
'Peter',float(53028.1),'2021-06-02',
'Peter',float(53916.1),'2021-06-03',
'Mary',float(50000),'2021-05-24',
'Mary',float(50035),'2021-05-25',
'Mary',float(53028.1),'2021-05-30'
) as (account_name,available_balance,Date_of_balance)
) --use your table instead of this CTE

select  account_name, available_balance, date_add(Date_of_balance,e.i) as Date_of_balance
from
( --Get next_date to generate date range
select account_name,available_balance,Date_of_balance,
       lead(Date_of_balance,1, Date_of_balance) over (partition by account_name order by Date_of_balance) next_date    
  from mytable d  --use your table
) s lateral view outer posexplode(split(space(datediff(next_date,Date_of_balance)-1),'')) e as i,x --generate rows
order by account_name desc, Date_of_balance --this is to have order of rows like in your Converted Table
```

Result:

```
account_name    available_balance   date_of_balance 
Peter           50000                2021-05-24
Peter           50035                2021-05-25
Peter           50035                2021-05-26
Peter           50035                2021-05-27
Peter           50610                2021-05-28
Peter           50610                2021-05-29
Peter           50610                2021-05-30
Peter           50610                2021-05-31
Peter           51710                2021-06-01
Peter           53028.1              2021-06-02
Peter           53916.1              2021-06-03
Mary            50000                2021-05-24
Mary            50035                2021-05-25
Mary            50035                2021-05-26
Mary            50035                2021-05-27
Mary            50035                2021-05-28
Mary            50035                2021-05-29
Mary            53028.1              2021-05-30
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo muchhhhh!!! this is exactly what I needed! You are the MVP!!

Comment: Hi leftjoin, if i used the same data you used, however I wanted both Mary and Peter accounts in the same date range, how would i go about doing this? For example set the date range between '2021-05-24' and '2021-06-03' and populate all balances during this period. If we take Mary as an example, I would also want to see Mary available balance of 53028.1 forward filled to the '2021-06-03'.

Comment: @AnthonyCape Ask new question please, need to think... and maybe someone will be faster than me

Comment: Updated question: Hi leftjoin, if i used the same data below and if I wanted both Mary and Peter accounts in the same date range, how would I amend the hive sql query to go about doing this? For example set the date range between '2021-05-24' and '2021-06-03' and populate all balances during this period. If we take Mary as an example, I would also want to see Mary available balance of '53028.1' forward filled to the '2021-06-03' and also if Mary didn't have a value on the '2021-05-24' to have it back filled with balance of '50000'.

Comment: Created a new stack overflow for it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68680069/hive-sql-query-to-fill-missing-date-values-in-table-with-nearest-values-between